# How to keep only one file into a folder and ignore the others with git?

Tags: git

I'm using `git` to controll the versions of my app, and I have a folder `Images` where I add many images of my app, then, I have a default image `default.jpg` and I want to keep this image and ignore the others when I do commit. Using the file `.gitignore` I can use `*.jpg` but it also ignore the `default.jpg` and I want to keep this image and ignore the others.

There's any way to do this ?

**My .gitignore**

```
/Images/*.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ! in your gitignore file.

In your situation:

```
/Images/*.jpg
!/Images/default.jpg
```